# Rexport all features from one module to another - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

How to export all features of one module via another. Something like in the pseudocode below:

Module one.js

```
exports.func1 = ...
exports.func2 = ...
exports.func2 = ...
```

Module two.js

```
 one = require 'one.js'

 exports = exportallfrom(one)
```

Module three.js

```
two = require 'two.js'

two.func1()
two.func2()
two.func3()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `two` inherit from `one`, using [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to establish a prototype chain between them:

```
module.exports = exports = Object.create require './one.js'

# ...
```

Or, you can simply iterate over `one`'s [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), copying their values:

```
one = require './one.js'
Object.keys(one).forEach (key) ->
  exports[key] = one[key]

# ...
```